# CYTOSCAPE COLA: Lock a node with animation enabled

Tags: graph, cytoscape.js, webcola

I'm using cytoscape-cola library to animate my graph using the `infinite:true` parameter in the layout section of cy element. I also added to my graph a function that lock the position of a node when clicked (like it happens, for example, in Neo4j).
Here's my function:

```
cy.on('click', 'node', function(ele){
    ele.lock=true;
});
```

The problem is that, when the function is triggered, I receive this error from cola.min.js:
Uncaught TypeError: i.locked is not a function.
If I disable animations (`infinite:false`), the function works, then I think locking nodes collides with animation function of cytoscape-cola.js. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: enable and disable locking dynamically based on animation

Comment: unfortunately animation in cytoscape regards the entire layout, not every single node separately